# Is getPreventDefault() deprecated?

Tags: javascript

If so which organization makes these decisions?  I'm trying to keep my code fresh and up to date and am getting warnings on some Browsers but not others regarding this method.

If it is Mozilla that deprecates these things, where on MDN can I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

> Is getPreventDefault() deprecated?

Mozilla say it is.

> If so which organization makes these decisions?

Usually the organization responsible for specifying it in the first place (unless a standards body adopted it from them).

In this case, `getPreventDefault` was a proprietary, non-standard method introduced by Mozilla. It does the same job as a standard property, so it was [deprecated](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726933#c0).

> where on MDN can I find this information

Generally on the page for the function / property in question or the object to which it is attached. In this case, there doesn't appear to be such a page.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a partial answer. Maybe this might be useful ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMEvent#getPreventDefault()

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was a newbie at that time :)